# PrimeFaces 3.2 DataTable "jump to page" paginator template?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

According to the official PrimeFaces 3.2 documentation, the paginator template can be a combination of the following predefined paginator templates:

- `{FirstPageLink}`
- `{LastPageLink}`
- `{PreviousPageLink}`
- `{NextPageLink}`
- `{PageLinks}`
- `{CurrentPageReport}`
- `{RowsPerPageDropDown}`

This is fine for small data sets, but it's extremely hard to navigate thru the pages if the data set is huge: imagine you have a few thousands (or even more) of pages, you're at the very first start, page No. 1, and you want to jump directly to page No. 813, and then -- to No. 499). So:

1. Is there a way to enhance the existing templates set for the paginator in PrimeFaces 3.2 DataTable, e.g. adding a custom template?
2. If not, ... is there a way (I assume it as a potential hack) affect the data table navigation like in the scenario I described above?

Your help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a paginator option `{JumpToPageDropdown}` you can use to select the page from the dropdown. I don't think it is documented.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I think you agree that page drop down is not very useful when there are a lot of pages.

Comment: Yes. You might want to add more information about your use case as appropriate. Here's why, there is always an option that you can write you renderer or javascript work around or hack. But it could also be a design issue. There might be useful alternatives like filter or tighter searches or maybe the later results are not as relevant e.g: google.com. Those would get looked at and an appropriate solution recommended by the community.

Comment: Unfortunately, the filtering to make the search result tighter is not so fine as it may sound for two reasons: 1) you have to know what filter you have to apply (especially if filterable values are far away from the first page); 2) that prevents superficial analysis harder because the filtered out rows are not visible for the target user. Roughly speaking, the intention is simply to let a user navigate quickly through the pages to analyze huge amounts of data by eye, or to get some feeling about the result data set.

Comment: Considering the `{JumpToPageDropdown}`: thanks a lot, true, that is an undocumented feature, and I easily found it in the PF 3.2 JAR as well as I found that in the `JumpToPageDropdownRenderer` and `DataRenderer` classes. The constructor of the `DataRenderer` has unfortunately hard-coded implementations of the `PaginatorElementRenderer` interfaces, so I seem have no opportunity to inject own renderer there.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the hints so now I know what I can do and what I can't do.